# Media query for iMac 5k resolution

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I,m trying to show eight column grid based **Flexbox** on iMac 5k display *(5120 × 2880)* but I could not understand which media query exactly I used for only 5K resolution !

```
@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
/* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

I also want only 5K resolution will effects, moreover in 4k display resolution its showing as i expected

Comment: Use `min-width`?

Comment: @jhpratt  If i use media query for  5k display then what it should be ? but it can not take effects on 4K display

Answer (score 5):

Most answers so far seem to ignore the difference between device pixels and "CSS pixels", which are dependent on the device's pixel density. I don't own a iMac 5K but I believe its screen depth is 2x, which means that, despite being a 5K, it will only display the equivalent to 2560*1440px (although very sharp, due to its double density). See [Designer's guide to DPI](http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/), by Sebastian Gabriel, which not only explains pixel density by also shows some iMacs as examples.

So, theoretically, if you want to target a 5K with a browser at full width, your media query would look something like:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:2560px) { 
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```

...or, possibly, a bit less than 2560 to try and capture situations in which the user doesn't have the browser occupying the full width of the screen.

However, truth is that this is not how you should build media queries. It is usually not important to target devices but instead to ensure that your content displays well and adjusts to different widths, no matter in which platform. Take your iMac 5K user. Maybe they won't use the browser filling out the full width of the screen but instead just half of it, so they can work on something else on the other half. Maybe they will zoom the page in or out, which also will impact what media query will apply. You need to worry with your grid adjusting well to all those possibilities, not the device being used.

It might also be worth adding that `-webkit...` media query options target browsers, specifically webkit based (Safari but also Chrome and others), and not devices. If your goal is indeed to target only iMac 5K users, assuming that they are browsing on Safari, you could also try something hacky like:

```css
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
    @media {
        /* CSS rules here */
    }
}
```

From [CSS3 Media Query to target only Internet Explorer (from IE6 to IE11+), Firefox, Chrome, Safari and/or Edge](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/#Safari_101), by Ryan.

You can also find other hacks at [browserhacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/).

Hacks, however, are also not good practice. As Browserhacks puts it, in their disclaimer:

> Please keep in mind using a hack is not always the perfect solution. It can be useful to fix some weird browser specific bug, but in most cases you should fix your CSS/JS or use [feature detection](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: You have shared a detailed article to understand, After checkout, I think we have to consider a lot of parameters then implement and test!!

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding any padding, scrollbars, etc. and assuming this is *only* for full screen displays, you'll want to use `@media (min-width: 5120px)`. You can combine this using `and` with the query you've provided to target devices more specifically (such as high-DPI).

The `5120px` value can (and likely should) be lowered, somewhere between the cutoff for a 4k and 5k display. This will allow the user to slightly shrink the browser, include a scrollbar, and more.

Comment: Could you write here media query for this section?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking. All you have to do is use what I provided and put braces on the end.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my projects I used this media query and its works perfect for me !

```
@media screen and (min-width: 2400px) {
    height: 650px;
}
```

Comment: As indicated by your comment on the question, the media query shouldn't take effect on 4K displays. This would.

Comment: Actually this media query works on my iMac 5k display !

Comment: That isn't what I said. Yes, it'll work on a 5k display, but will also work on smaller displays (unlike other answers, including my own). This is in direct contradiction with your original question.

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 3334px) {
        .container-index1 {
            max-width: 2500px;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Since the iMac 4k width is 4096px and iMac 5k width is 5120px. This media query will work between those resolution

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 4095px) and (max-width : 5120px) {

}
```

Comment: This is wrong, iMac are ratina dsiplays. You can't just use physical resolution as css resolutions. Depending upon the dpi the css media query would be much smaller.