# media query for 5k desktop screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to optimise my application for 5K desktop screens (5120 x 2880) like the `iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017)`.

I am having bother implementing the correct media query that will allow me to target and modify the elements within such.

As it currently stands, My largest working media query is for 1080p Full HD Television which works well.

**1920 x 1080**

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1824px) {

      #product-details-main {
        width: 32.4%;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 600px;
        padding: 0 0 0 1%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 140px;
     }



}
```

A similar question was asked on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022979/media-query-for-imac-5k-resolution) before but the solutions have not worked.

Any steering would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at the rendered resolution. I mean a phonescreen can contain a full hd screen while only 480x800px are rendered

Comment: my apologies, I meant for desktop devices, I have edited the post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min-device-width` instead of just `min-width` in your media query, in combination with `min-device-pixel-ratio` That way you should be able to address large high resolution screens.

Addition after comment:

Well, if the 5k screens you are targeting are 5120px wide and have a DPR of 2, those are the values you should be using. It depends on the device (i.e. the same won't work for a 4k screen)

Comment: what pixel value should I be targeting. please update your answer